# UIBarButtonItem with image and blue text incorrectly turns into white text when disabled

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want a UIBarButtonItem with a custom image and blue text. I have made this by creating a  UIButton with the text, font colour and image first, and then setting a custom view for the UIBarButtonItem.

The problem is that when I disable the UIBarButtonItem the text goes back to white. I have no idea why.

```
UIButton *customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[customButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"images/ButtonHeader"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customButton setTitle:myDynamicText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 70.0f, 44.0f)];
[customButton addTarget:myTarget action:myAction forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[customButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12.0f]];
[customButton.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

UIBarButtonItem *customBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customButton];

self.navigationBar.rightBarButtonItem = customBarButtonItem;
self.navigationBar.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

What I really want to do is have different text colour for enabled and disabled state, but I can figure that part out myself if someone can tell me why the text turns white when enabled=NO, and how to stop that.

Comment: you can use this method of UIButton: - (void)setTitleColor:(UIColor *)color forState:(UIControlState)state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be setting the font colour by getting the label like that. You need to configure it on the button

```
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

`UIControlStateNormal` will act to set the default values, but then you can change the color for all the different states. A list of these states is available at the bottom of [UIControl Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) under `Control State`